# Get JSON from PHP and display it in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a SQL database linking to a PHP page which produces the following JSON:

`[{"ID":"1","SubjectName":"Subject 1"},{"ID":"2","SubjectName":"Subject 2"}]`

I was wondering how to format and display this in a separate HTML page. For example:
(Using JQuery Mobile)

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-divider-theme="b" data-inset="true">
    <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">Subject1</li>
    <li data-theme="c">1</li>
    <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading">Subject2</li>
    <li data-theme="c">2</li>
</ul>
```

---

```
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password)
    or die("Unable to connect to MySQL at".$hostname/"<br />");

//Select Database
$selected = mysql_select_db($databasename,$dbhandle)
    OR die("Could not select Database:".$databasename."<br />");

//SQL Query
$result = mysql_query("SELECT ID, SubjectName FROM Subject");
$rows = array();

while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
    }
print json_encode($rows);
//while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
//  echo "ID:".$row{'ID'}." Subject:".$row{'SubjectName'}."<br />";
//  }

mysql_close($dbhandle);
?>
```

---

I'm using PhoneGap, so I can only use Javascript to do this.

---

I have found some tutorials, but they use JSON from the URL, but this is only displaying on the page.

Comment: Can you add few lines how you read JSON from URL and show what you are doing. I belive still you are getting your JSON into a string. So if you read it from a file read it into a string.

Comment: @dinesh707 I have added the PHP, it doesn't do anything to the URL, just places the string into the body of the page.
The tutorials I have seen all use JSON strings which are part of the URL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON `{"ID":"1","SubjectName":"Subject 1"}`

---

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'THE_URL_YOU_GET_THE_DATA_FROM',
    dataType: 'json'
    success: getInfo1
});
function getInfo1(json) {
    var r = '<ul data-role="listview">';
    var l = json.length;
    for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
        r += '<li><h4>' + json[i].SubjectName+ '</h4><p>ID: ' + json[i].ID. + '</li>';
        }
        document.getElementById('someDiv').innerHTML = r + '</ul>';
    }
```

---

This will then pull the data from the php page and will insert the content into the Div element assigned as `someDiv`

Answer (score 2):

An option could be using **AJAX** or any implementation like **jQuery**.

You can use the jQuery AJAX object in the **html** file like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

1. **type** is the method to send the info, post or get
2. **url** is the PHP file
3. **data** is used if you want to pass any variable as parameter
4. **success** you put the following code to a success communication, in this section you can assign the **JSON** results to the fields in the html file
5. **datatype** you put wheter json or xml

If you want, you can use a reduced **jQuery Object** just like this code :

```
$.post('ajax/test.php', function(data) {
  $('#result').html(data);
});
```

1. **ajax/test.php** is the PHP file
2. **data** is the json that you generate in PHP file
3. **'#result'** is the identifier (ID) of your html element
4. **.html(data)**  you are assigning the json to the html element

When you get a JSON object as a response you can access your elements as follows:

**data.id, data.name or data.lastName**

Then you can write as this

```
 function send(){
    $.post('ajax/test.php', function(data) {
      if(data.error == 'false'){
        $('#id').html(data.id);
        $('#name').html(data.name);
        $('#lastName').html(data.lastName);
      }
      else{
        alert('Error in communication due ' + data.error);
      }
    });
}
```

**UPDATE**

This could be an example of a HTML form ready to use the jQuery function described above. (Note the **onClick** method is calling the a javascript function called **send()**),

**Note**: I modified the jQuery code with the HTML to match the example.

```
<form id="form">
   SomeId <input type="text" id="id" />
   Name <input type ="text" id="name" />
   Last Name <input type ="text" id="lastName" />
   <input type="submit" value="Send" onClick="send()" />
</form>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm quite new to this, can you add the HTML markup as well?